# Optimizing jQuery speed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, optimization, performance

I am trying to use jQuery's fancy autocomplete function but I have a problem with speed of executing my script. Code snippet:

```
var data =  <?php if(isset($names)) { echo json_encode(implode(" | ", array_unique($names))); } else { echo "null"; } ?>;
if (data != null) {
    data = data.split(" | ");
    $("#search_names").autocomplete(data);
}
```

My data comes from some MySQL table and is processed by PHP before jQuery pass it to input field. When I view source of such page there's enormous amount of text there (obviously) and the page itself loads between 5-10 seconds...

So I wonder is there a way to speed up my script somehow? I understand that there will be *always* so much text to process, whether in same file or in some other included file, but I just wonder am I stuck with 10sec loading page because of so much data or can I somehow make it more awesome? :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I know this isn't really part of you question but it is a bit odd to implode an array and then json_encode when `json_encode` is meant to preserve you data structure. you could use `data = JSON.parse(data);` in your javscript in stead of the split. This prevents problems when your data starts including other charactes (like `|`)

Comment: Hmm, ok I see... Will try to fix that for sure... Thanks for noticing ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your using the following scritp: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

You should be using Ajax for this sort of thing, example:

```
 $("#search_names").autocomplete('/ajax/autocomplete.php');
```

and then within your auto complete html you should do something like:

```
<?php
    //Database
    //Do Query: SELECT item FROM content WHERE {$escaped_q} ORDER BY item_hits DESC LIMIT {$escaped_limit}

   //echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Print the results as a JSON Object and it should work MUCH MUCH Faster.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely use the [remote autocomplete mechanism](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) instead of filling all the data into the document every time.

> The first argument can be an URL for remote data or an an array for local data.
>
> For remote data: When the user starts typing, a request is send to the specified backend ("my_autocomplete_backend.php"), with a GET parameter named q that contains the current value of the input box and a parameter "limit" with the value specified for the max option.

if the lookups still take a lot of time, you will probably need to look into optimizing your PHP script instead of the jQuery part. Things like is the database using indexes, etc....